# Erro ao imprimir Array List em Java

Tags: java, printf, print

Estou fazendo um código onde é criado um ArrayList da classe "Empregado"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int qntFuncionarios;
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    List <Empregado> list = new ArrayList<Empregado>();
    

    System.out.println("Favor informar a quantidade de funcionarios que queira cadastrar: ");
    qntFuncionarios = sc.nextInt();
    

    
    for (int i=0; i<qntFuncionarios;i++)
    {
        Empregado empregado = new Empregado();
        System.out.println("Informar o id do funcionario: ");
        empregado.id = sc.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("\n Informar o nome do funcionário: ");
        empregado.nome = sc.next();
        System.out.println("\n Informar o salario do usuário: ");
        empregado.salario = sc.nextDouble();
        list.add(new Empregado());
    
    }
    
    for (Empregado x : list)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    
    
}
```

}

Porém, quando eu faço a impressão através do for each, eu recebo esse padrão de saída

> "aulaLista.Empregado@7d4991ad"

pelo o que eu andei pesquisando, tem algo a ver com o método *toString*, porém não encontrei uma solução ainda.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Empregado x : list)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

No seu código você está dando um System.out.println no objeto inteiro, se não me engano isso retornará o hashCode do objeto, para retornar os atributos faça igual no exemplo abaixo:

```
 for (Empregado x : list)
 {
        System.out.println(x.id);
 System.out.println(x.nome);
    }
```

Comment: Realmente eu consegui sair desse hashCode, porém eu me deparei com outro problema, parece que as informações inseridas, ID, nome e salário não estão dentro da lista, pois na saida aparece apenas os valores nulos, ao invés de aparecer os valores informados anteriormente

Comment: @OpufPaulistano É porque vc está fazendo `list.add(new Empregado())`, ou seja, está adicionano um novo `Empregado` (e com os dados não preenchidos). Em vez disso, vc deveria adicionar o que já teve os dados preenchidos: `list.add(empregado)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode solucionar seu problema de duas maneiras, na primeira delas você pode sobrescrever o método `toString` da classe empregado, isso te permite manter o trecho de código apresentado em seu atual estado, o processo ocorre da seguinte forma:

```
public class Empregado {

   @Override
   public String toString() {
          return nome;
   }

}
```

A segunda forma é você chamar o método de acesso ao nome do empregado no momento de "printa-lo", para tal, faça da seguinte maneira:

```
list.forEach(empregado -> {
        System.out.println(empregado.getNome());
});
```